# dotenv equivalent for visual studio machine-specific macros

Tags: c++, visual-studio

We have a Visual Studio C++ project hosted on GitHub, and want to keep personal macros on one's own machine, and don't get committed to the git history, just like the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for js.

For example, in one machine called `A` I want to define a macros `MACHINE_A`, and another machine called `B` I want to define a macros `MACHINE_B`. After set up, in my `.cpp` file, I can do all machine specific
things like this:

```cpp
#ifdef MACHINE_A
    QString imageFileName = "/Users/username/projects/xxx/xxx.tif";
#elif defined(MACHINE_B)
    QString imageFileName = "C:\\xxx\\some\\other\\path.tif";
#else
    QString imageFileName =
        QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            this, "Open Image file",
            QStandardPaths::writableLocation(
                QStandardPaths::StandardLocation::DocumentsLocation),
            tr(getSuppportedImageFormatsText()));
#endif
```

How can I achieve this using Visual Studio? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for [props setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the correction! I will read the docs about props settings.

Comment: Add the machine specific files to your .gitignore. Or a whole folder.